# Bypassed, Empty Relay Log

Tags: mysql, replication

We have a simple 1:1 Master-Slave replication configuration. The Master crashed, but we recovered and replication seems fine (confirmed by pt-heartbeat and SHOW SLAVE STATUS) but we've picked up one small, strange issue: there is an old, empty, and bypassed relay log hanging out on the Slave.

We are on relay.000725, and this one is relay.000724, so we're past it. What's more, it doesn't contain any actual queries. Just the meta data.

Can I delete this? What caused this?

```
> /*!50530 SET @@SESSION.PSEUDO_SLAVE_MODE=1*/; /*!40019 SET
> @@session.max_insert_delayed_threads=0*/; /*!50003 SET
> @OLD_COMPLETION_TYPE=@@COMPLETION_TYPE,COMPLETION_TYPE=0*/; DELIMITER
> /*!*/;
> # at 4
> #140704  3:36:04 server id 16  end_log_pos 107    Start: binlog v 4, server v 5.5.38 created 140704  3:36:04 BINLOG '
> ZFm2Uw8QAAAAZwAAAGsAAAAAAAQANS41LjM4AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
> AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEzgNAAgAEgAEBAQEEgAAVAAEGggAAAAICAgCAA==
> '/*!*/;
> # at 107
> #140721  4:22:51 server id 14  end_log_pos 1073741944     Rotate to bin-log.006142  pos: 4
> # at 148
> #140704  3:36:04 server id 16  end_log_pos 187    Rotate to relay.000725  pos: 4 DELIMITER ;
> # End of log file ROLLBACK /* added by mysqlbinlog */; /*!50003 SET COMPLETION_TYPE=@OLD_COMPLETION_TYPE*/; /*!50530 SET
> @@SESSION.PSEUDO_SLAVE_MODE=0*/;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You be able to delete it without issues. Why ?

Look for the file `relay-log.index` and display it

```
# cat relay-log.index
```

You will see a list of relay logs MySQL Replication needs and rotates. If `relay.000724` is not in `relay.index`, you can delete `relay.000724` without breaking anything.

Why is is still around ? It could be anything. Between setting up replication after an outrage, skipping SQL Errors, and just plain Starting and Stopping, along with a low [**expire_logs_days**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_expire_logs_days) could leave one or more relay logs lingering.

In light of these things, if a relay log does not appear in `relay.index`, you can delete it.

## Why is the relay log so empty ?

It has to do with the mechanism Replication uses to rotate to the next relay log. You will not see these annoying little files very often. The only time I usually see them is with one of the following:

- when the SQL thread is broken
- when the SQL thread is extremely busy with a long running query

In either case, the IO thread keeps collecting binlog events. Instead of triggering a rotation when the relay log reaches 1G or whatever [max_binlog_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_binlog_size) or [max_relay_log_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_relay_log_size) is, two little relay logs with nothing in them mark the place where a rotation would have occurred.

## UPDATE 2014-07-21 15:28 EDT

Since the `relay-log.index` both relay logs, there are one of two things you could do:

- Leave it alone and let MySQL Replication rotate it away on its own
- Reset all the relay logs back to `relay-log.000001` with the following

  - Run `STOP SLAVE;`
  - Run `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G`
  - Find `Relay_Master_Log_File` in the Status (say it is `mysql-bin.001234`)
  - Find `Exec_Master_Log_File` in the Status (say it is `123789456`)
  - Run `CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.001234',MASTER_LOG_POS=123789456;`
  - Run `START SLAVE;`

Comment: okay, that's great info. But it DOES appear in the relay-log.index! /Volumes/B/mysql/relay.000724
/Volumes/B/mysql/relay.000725 It's very weird, as show, it is completely empty.

Comment: Many thanks by the way, Rolando, you've answered more than one of my questions.

Comment: You made a type in the question. You said `relay-log.000274`.

Comment: Look in the question again, you said `relay.000274`. I think you meant `relay.000724`.

Comment: good advice. I will try and let mysql take care of it naturally. If it does not, then I will attempt your second suggestion. It wouldn't matter, but something we check on to tell us our replication system is healthy is number of old relay logs, and this showing up in there is throwing an alert. Thanks again Rolando!

Comment: As long as every relay log is inside `relay.index`, you need not worry. What you should be monitoring is the `Relay_Log_Space` in the `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G`. This is the sum of all relay log filesizes. If that number grows, that alert should be raised in case you have a broken SQL thread (IO thread keeps collecting Master binlog events) or the SQL thread has many long running queries to process one by one. This can also manifest itself with an increasing `Seconds_Behind_Master`.